# how to add icon fontawesome on :title nav-tab bootstrap vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, font-awesome, vuex, bootstrap-vue

how to add font awesome on :title tab bootstrap vue.js?

```
<b-tab :title="'Sebagai '+application_config.studentLabel+' <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>'" active><p>I'm the first tab</p></b-tab>
```

I tried but an error.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap Vue `Slots` for `tabs` component

```
<template v-slot:title>
  //add other data
  //add icon like 
   <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
 </template>
```

you can find in documentations as [Add custom content to tab title](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/#tabs)